# MatLab input argument error with objective function and fmincon()

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am working through an example using `fmincon()`.

I define my objective function in `objFun.m`

```
function f=objFun(x)
    f = 100*(x(2) - (x(1))^2)^2 + (1 - x(1))^2;
end
```

and I define an initial point x0

`x0=[1; -1]`

And if I run the objective function with that point as a test I get

```
>> objFun(x0)

ans =

   400
```

But when I try to use it in `fmincon()` I get

```
>> [x, fval] = fmincon(objFun, x0, [1;2],1,[],[],[0; -inf],[inf, 0]);
Not enough input arguments.

Error in objFun (line 2)
    f = 100*(x(2) - (x(1))^2)^2 + (1 - x(1))^2;
```

I suspect I'm missing something very simple here, but what?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a handle to the function `@objFun` not the function itself, and your `A` and `x0` matrix need to be transposed, ie: a row with 2 columns, each row in `A` is another linear constraint.

```matlab
x0=[1, -1];
A = [1,2];
b = 1;
[x, fval] = fmincon(@objFun, x0, A,b,[],[],[0; -inf],[inf; 0]);

function f=objFun(x)
    f = 100*(x(2) - (x(1))^2)^2 + (1 - x(1))^2;
end
```